# Android Studio: App crashes when numbers are not inputted

Tags: java, android, input, crash

The button works fine when I input numbers, but it crashes when I don't. To resolve this I tried using a conditional statement so that the calculate button wont run if there are no numbers inputted, but it still doesn't work. I put an else line to see if it prints anything, but still nothing.

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //This is where I tried to fix it
            if (percentageText.getText()!=null && numberText.getText()!=null){
                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageText.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberText.getText().toString());
                totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
                Log.d("myTag","Success!");
            } else {
               Log.d("myTag","Error no integer found");
            }
        }
```

Here's the logcat:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN3DO.png)

But it shouldn't matter if I parse float since the if statement prevents the code from being ran, right? Or does it try to run anyways?

Comment: Have you tried surrounding it with `try-catch`?

Comment: can you post logcat error here?

Comment: you are parsing to `float` this could be the problem. Show your logcat for more info.

Comment: try adding another condition check along with your null condition check.
(numberText.getText().toString().trim().getlength > 0 ) or 
(! numberText.getText().toString().trim().equalignourcase(""))
apply this for both percentage edittext and numbertext edittext

Comment: @v-v Your solution worked, thank you!

Comment: can i add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding another condition check along with your null condition check.

```
(numberText.getText().toString().trim().getlength > 0 ) or (! numberText.getText().toString().trim().equalignourcase(""))
```

apply this for both percentage edittext and numbertext edittext

Answer (score 0):

To force input number in edittext, you can set this property to edittext:

```
android:inputType="number"
```